# What is TDOT subroutine in BLAS?

Tags: fortran, tensor, blas, numpy-einsum

I tried to use [opt-einsum](https://optimized-einsum.readthedocs.io/en/stable/) to generate contraction path for Fortran implementation and I came across an expression `TDOT`
https://optimized-einsum.readthedocs.io/en/stable/greedy_path.html?highlight=tdot

> scaling        BLAS                current                             remaining

> 4           TDOT            tfp,fr->tpr                              tpr->tpr

I cannot find it in http://www.netlib.org/lapack/explore-html/index.html or other BLAS webpage after a few searching :(

What is it in BLAS?

Comment: As the page is talking about tensors and Hadamard products, isn't it likely that "tdot" is simply "tensor dot product" rather than a BLAS routine?

Comment: No idea... I found it is under BLAS column, wonder if it is some subroutine in BLAS...

Comment: TDOT is not start of the standard BLAS interface

Comment: http://dl.acm.org/ft_gateway.cfm?id=2949580&ftid=1785218&dwn=1&CFID=968826392&CFTOKEN=87667834 may be of use: "The ‘tdot’ operation expresses a general tensor contraction. " On a very quick glance through the paper appears to discuss an implementation of a blas-like library for tensor linear algebra

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is correct, TDOT is not part of BLAS. If we look at this particular expression we see that the data needs to be organized before a BLAS call can happen as the "zip" index `f` is not on the left or right hand side of each tensor.

```
TDOT            tfp,fr->tpr
---
tmp_tpf = tfp -> tpf # Reogrganize data
tmp_tpf,fr -> tpr    # Standard BLAS call with `f` as the zip index
```

There are some libraries such as [TBLIS](https://github.com/devinamatthews/tblis) which expand upon BLAS functionality and allow for non-contiguous expressions by transposing data as blocks are moved from RAM to cache for extremely high performance. TDOT is explicitly stated in the `opt_einsum` docs since it is generally *not* a good thing due to the memory copy before contraction; the memory copy can often be the bottleneck!

Quick note I'm the author of `opt_einsum`, I would love a PR if you get the chance!